# log4j Writing Logs to File

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j to write the logs to file and its working perfectly. However I am having few issues here.

The application accepts few arguments and I am validating the arguments for its correctness.
Based on the arguments I am framing the log file name and only if all arguments are correct the logging starts. But in case the arguments are wrong ,the logging never happens as the log file is not created.
So, how can I overcome this issue and start logging right from the first line after main().

```
class Test{
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
    public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length < 5) {
                logger.error("Invalid arguments passed to program...."); //Not written to log file
                System.exit(1);
            }

    String id = args[0];
    String name = args[1].toLowerCase();
    String date = args[2];
    String batch = args[3];
    String file = args[4];

    String logfile = id + "_" + name + "_" + date + "_" + batch;
    System.setProperty("logfile", logfile);
    ConfigParser conf = new ConfigParser(propFile);
    String log = conf.getSetting("log4jConfPath");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log);

    //logs written to file from this point
```

I want that the logging should start from the 1st line in main()

```
#log file

log4j.rootLogger=INFO , file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x #%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.File=${logfile}.log
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add a [mre], a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org) or at least show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @yur Updated the question with example

Comment: can you Show your log configuration? Where the first log Statement should be written if you specify the file Name some files later?

Comment: Does [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig) help in any way?

Comment: @Jens, added the log config

Comment: What is the value of `${logfile}` if the program starts?

Comment: value of ${logfile} is set in the main() . `System.setProperty("logfile", logfile);`

Comment: Yes but  after the first logentry. So again my question, where should the error be loged if the logfile is not set at time of logging?

Comment: yes I understand that, So i would like to know if there is  some other way to make it work?

Comment: Add a Default logfile and write to it until the properties are checked

Comment: I don't want to maintain two log files.

Comment: Than do not use user Input for logfile Name or print the error message to the console, not into a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jens's comments. But if you really want to use the user input for log file name and log the first line as well, then what you can do is, instead of passing it as a program argument, you can pass it as JVM argument when executing the program.

*-Dlogfile=my-log-file.log*

If you don't want to use the JVM argument, then you are out of luck.

Comment: How should I pass -Dlogfile to spark-submit?

Comment: `--driver-java-options -Dlogfilename=my-log-file.log`